# Splitting an identified range of spreadsheets to a new workbook with a new name

Tags: vba, excel, split

I've been trying to come up with a way to split a workbook into separate workbooks based on identified worksheets in the workbook.

For example:
Say I had a worksheet for every letter in the alphabet.

I would want to split worksheets A through C into a new workbook named "A through C."

D through I will go into a new workbook named "D through I."

etc...

My idea would be to first insert a worksheet that in column A names the new workbook it will become and Columns b through as many columns as there are will the names of the worksheets to be copied into the new workbook.

Does anyone have an idea of how to make a macro for this? I've tried myself but have been unsuccessful.

Thank you!

I found this Macro out there. Does anyone think it can be modified to work?

```
Sub Test()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim List As New Collection
Dim Item As Variant
Dim WB As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = Sh.Range("A2:A" & Sh.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Rng
    List.Add c.Value, CStr(c.Value)
Next c
On Error GoTo 0
Set Rng = Sh.Range("A1:H" & Sh.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
For Each Item In List
    Set WB = Workbooks.Add
    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Item
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy WB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    Rng.AutoFilter
    With WB
        .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Item & ".xls"
        .Close
    End With
Next Item
Sh.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Yes, that would be quite easy.  As you suggest, have a control sheet.  My suggestion would be have the new filename in column A, and then the sheets to go into that file in columns B, C, D, etc.  Then you can just loop down column A, on each row create a workbook, loop across the row copying those worksheets to the new workbook, and then save the file.  If you have troubles, paste some code here showing where you got stuck and we can assist.

Comment: You should add what code you have created yourself. When you don't show any code the SO community will typically take that as a sign that you are trying to get someone to write the code for you.

Comment: Thank you for your input @YowE3K. I've added what I am working with. Do you think I am on the right track?

Comment: You have shown some effort by posting some code that vaguely resembles what you are trying to do, so I am now happy to help you expand it so that it works.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code assumes you have your control sheet (named "Split Parameters") in the workbook containing the macro, and it is set out with the desired filenames in column A, and the sheets that you wish to copy into that file (from the ActiveWorkbook, which might, or might not, be the one containing the macro) listed in columns B, C, etc.  Row 1 is assumed to be headings, and is therefore ignored.

```
Sub SplitBook()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim srcWB As Workbook
    Dim newWB As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim XPath As String
    Dim newName As String
    Dim sheetName As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating =  False
    Application.DisplayAlerts =  False
    Set srcWB = ActiveWorkbook
    XPath = srcWB.Path
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Split Parameters")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            'Take the first worksheet and create a new workbook
            sheetName = .Cells(i, "B").Value
            srcWB.Sheets(sheetName).Copy
            Set newWB = ActiveWorkbook
            'Now process all the other sheets that need to go into this workbook
            LastColumn = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For c = 3 To LastColumn
                sheetName = .Cells(i, c).Value
                srcWB.Sheets(sheetname).Copy After:=newWB.Sheets(newWb.Sheets.Count)
            Next
            'Save the new workbook
            newName = .Cells(i, "A").Value
            newWB.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & newName & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8
            newWB.Close False
        Next
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts =  True
    Application.ScreenUpdating =  True
End Sub
```

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thank you so much. This is going to save so much time on a weekly basis.